# Creating input splits (HADOOP)

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop2

I have a file with size **39MB**, I set the block size as **36MB**. When the file is uploaded to HDFS, it successfully stores the file in two blocks. Now when I run a Map-Reduce job(simple reading job) on this file, the job counters show : 
"**INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1**"

That is , it is considering the 2 blocks as a single split, so I looked around and found the formula for calculating the split size which is as follows:

**split size = max(minsize,min(maxsize,blocksize))**

where **minsize=mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize** and **maxsize=minsize=mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize**.

Now in my MR code I set the following properties:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration()
conf.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize","1")
conf.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize","134217728")
```

That is minsize=1 byte and maxsize=128 MB, so according to the formula the split size should be 36MB and hence two splits should be there, but still I am getting the same counter output as :

"**INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1**"

Can anyone explain why ?

Comment: What kind of file is it?

Comment: It's a .csv file @BinaryNerd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last split of a file can overflow by 10%.
This is called as `SPLIT_SLOP` and it is set at `1.1`.

In this scenario,

```
39MB (Remaining Bytes) / 36MB (Input Split Size) = 1.08 is less than 1.1 (SPLIT_SLOP)
```

Thus the entire file is considered as one split.

Snippet on how splits are divided,

```
long bytesRemaining = FileSize;
while (((double) bytesRemaining)/splitSize > SPLIT_SLOP) {
  String[][] splitHosts = getSplitHostsAndCachedHosts(blkLocations,length-bytesRemaining, splitSize, clusterMap);
  splits.add(makeSplit(path, length-bytesRemaining, splitSize,splitHosts[0], splitHosts[1]));
  bytesRemaining -= splitSize;
}
```

Refer [getSplits()](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.java#L386) method to know how splits are divided for each file.

Comment: This (Remaining bytes) is the TOTAL FILE SIZE ?

Comment: In this case, since file size is small, it looks like entire file goes in as remaining bytes. For ex: if the Filse size is `75MB`, then you will have 2 splits. 1st split will be `36MB` and 2nd split will be `39MB`. The Remaining bytes changes for every split division. Refer updated answer

Comment: Can we override the value of SPLIT_SLOP ? Most importantly, should we override that value ?

Comment: This value is hardcoded and no provision to override is provided AFAIK.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much for your input !